# Centering a CMFCPropertySheet?

Tags: mfc

This is the constructor for my derived:  `CMFCPropertySheet`:

```
OtherSettingsSheet::COtherSettingsSheet(UINT nIDCaption, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT iSelectPage)
    :CMFCPropertySheet(nIDCaption, pParentWnd, iSelectPage)
{
    m_psh.dwFlags |= PSH_NOAPPLYNOW;
    SetIconsList(IDB_BMP_OTHER_SETTINGS, 32);
    SetLook(CMFCPropertySheet::PropSheetLook_OutlookBar);

    AddPage(&m_pageEmailSettings);
}

COtherSettingsSheet::COtherSettingsSheet(LPCTSTR pszCaption, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT iSelectPage)
    :CMFCPropertySheet(pszCaption, pParentWnd, iSelectPage)
{
    m_psh.dwFlags |= PSH_NOAPPLYNOW;
    SetIconsList(IDB_BMP_OTHER_SETTINGS, 32);
    SetLook(CMFCPropertySheet::PropSheetLook_OutlookBar);

    AddPage(&m_pageEmailSettings);
}
```

Is there any setting to center the property sheet other than calling `CenterWindow`? What is the right way to get the sheet to be central?

[image: CMFCPropertySheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only solution that I know of:

```
BOOL COtherSettingsSheet::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL bResult = CMFCPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();

    CenterWindow();

    return bResult;
}
```

I am just surprised that the control does center anyway.